# Trying to send simple data from server to react native client-side

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, frontend, backend

I am trying to send data from server.js using express and node.js to my client-side which is in React Native, both sides work individually but aren't communicating with each other. I am fairly new to backend development so I am beginning to understand how it functions and how to implement required behaviors. Please can anyone help?

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' })
}
)





app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Modal, StyleSheet, View, StatusBar,Text, ActivityIndicator,  FlatList} from 'react-native'


export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Call our fetch function below once the component mounts
  this.callBackendAPI()
    .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
  // Fetches our GET route from the Express server. (Note the route we are fetching matches the GET route from server.js
callBackendAPI = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/');
  const body = await response.json();

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw Error(body.message) 
  }
  return body;
};



  render(){


    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
 <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>


      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',

  },

});
```

package.Json

```
{
  "name": "mapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-mobx-deep-action": "^1.6.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.3",
    "jsc-android": "241213.x.x",
    "mobx": "^5.11.0",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.10",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-background-geolocation": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-css-gradient": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-drop-down-item": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-input-scroll-view": "^1.9.3",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.5.6",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.5.2",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-vertical-tab-view": "^0.1.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try updating the url to the full url of your local server:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000');
```

Check the port matches your express server port ^^